# Flume Hive sink failed to serialize JSON with array

Tags: hadoop, hive, flume, flume-ng

I am trying to load JSON data to Hive via Hive Sink.
But it fails with the following error:

```
WARN org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe: Error [java.io.IOException: Field name expected] parsing json text [{"id": "12345", "url": "https://mysite", "title": ["MyTytle"]}].
INFO org.apache.flume.sink.hive.HiveWriter: Parse failed : Unable to convert byte[] record into Object  : {"id": "12345", "url": "https://mysite", "title": ["MyTytle"]}
```

Example of data:

```
{"id": "12345", "url": "https://mysite", "title": ["MyTytle"]}
```

Description of Hive table:

```
id              string                                      
url             string                                      
title           array<string>                               
time            string                                      

# Partitions
time            string
```

And the same way it works fine if JSON data doesn't contain arrays (and Hive table either).

Flume version: 1.7.0 (Cloudera CDH 5.10)

Does it possible to load JSON data  with arrays via Flume Hive sink?

Answer (score 0):

*Is it possible to load JSON data with arrays via Flume Hive sink?*

I assume it is possible, despite I never tried myself. From:

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_HDP_RelNotes/content/ch01s08s02.html

> Following serializers are provided for Hive sink:
>
> JSON: Handles UTF8 encoded Json (strict syntax) events and requires no
>   configuration. Object names in the JSON are mapped directly to columns
>   with the same name in the Hive table. Internally uses
>   org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe but is independent of the
>   Serde of the Hive table. This serializer requires HCatalog to be
>   installed.

So maybe you are implementing something wrong in the SerDe. This user solved the problem of serialising a JSON with arrays by performing a previous regexp:

[Parse json arrays using HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447428/parse-json-arrays-using-hive)

Another thing you may try is to change the SerDe. At least you have this two options (maybe there are some more):

- 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
- 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
  (https://github.com/sheetaldolas/Hive-JSON-Serde/tree/master)