# Loading JSON data into hive tables

Tags: json, hive, hive-serde

I've tried loading simple `JSON` records from a file into hive tables like as shown below. Each `JSON` record is in a separate line.

```
{"Industry":"Manufacturing","Phone":null,"Id":null,"type":"Account","Name":"Manufacturing"}
{"Industry":null,"Phone":"(738) 244-5566","Id":null,"type":"Account","Name":"Sales"}
{"Industry":"Government","Phone":null,"Id":null,"type":"Account","Name":"Kansas City Brewery & Co"}
```

But I couldn't find any `serde` to load the array of comma `(,)` separated `JSON` records into the hive table. Input is a file containing `JSON` records as shown below...

```
[{"Industry":"Manufacturing","Phone":null,"Id":null,"type":"Account","Name":"Manufacturing"},{"Industry":null,"Phone":"(738) 244-5566","Id":null,"type":"Account","Name":"Sales"},{"Industry":"Government","Phone":null,"Id":null,"type":"Account","Name":"Kansas City Brewery & Co"}]
```

Can someone suggest me a `serde` which can parse this `JSON` file?

Thanks

Comment: I am getting the second example (array of JSON records) from mulesoft application. I am unable to load this data onto hive tables using `serde`s. But when I tried with first example (each record in a separate row), the serde works fine

Comment: This is the format that I get from the mulesoft application and I am sure that it is in the correct JSON format.
Ref: https://adobe.github.io/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html

Comment: Hive has been designed to process tables made of *records*, stored in huge *files*. What you get is a small *message* that is supposed to be processed by an application, and possibly streamed into a table. Just do that: build an app that streams messages into a Hive table.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this serde : https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Another related post : [Parse json arrays using HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447428/parse-json-arrays-using-hive)

Comment: Have you verified that the suggested SerDe can answer to the OP needs?