# extracting field from JSON using HIVE

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I have one issue in my hive code. I want to extract JSON data from using HIVE.Following is the sample json format

```
{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"versionModified"{"machine":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","state":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}
```

I want to get the following fields

- ver
- type
- vehicle
- ts
- founder
- state

the issue is founder and state is in one array "version"
can anybody help how to get rid of this?
some times instead of versionmedified   something else may come

**eg:**
some times my data will be like

```
{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"anotherCriteria":{"engine":"123.dfer","developer":"3.0","state":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}
```

adding  some sample data below:

```
{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC"{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}


{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"GAP"{"XVY":"123.dfer","FAH":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}


{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"BOX"{"VOG":"123.dfer","FAH":"3.0","FAX":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}
```

i need to put this data into various tables based on version if it is "BOX" the put in one table if it is "GAP" put another...

Comment: refer this to use get_json_object in hive....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447428/parse-json-arrays-using-hive

Comment: Please show your table schema

Comment: Don't mix questions. Open a new question for the INSERTissue

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz  can u help me with the problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383544/inserting-json-data-from-one-table-to-another-tables-in-hive/43393158#43393158

Answer (score 1):

you can use json serde to fetch all fields

Just follow below steps

1.Download json serde  from http://www.congiu.net/hive-json-serde/1.3/

2.Add json serde Jar

> ```
> hive> ADD jar /root/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
> Added [/root/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar] to class path
> Added resources: [/root/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar]
> ```

3.create table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE json_serde_table (
>   Rtype struct<ver:int, os:string,type:string,vehicle:string,MOD: struct<Version:Array<struct<versionModified:struct<machine:string,founder:string,state:string,fashion:string,cdc:string,dof:string,ts:string>>>>>
> )
> ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';
> ```

4.load json file into table

> ```
> hive> load data local inpath '/root/json.txt' INTO TABLE json_serde_table;
> Loading data to table default.json_serde_table
> Table default.json_serde_table stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=234]
> OK
> Time taken: 0.877 seconds
> ```

5.Fire below query to get result

```
hive> select Rtype.ver ver ,Rtype.type type ,Rtype.vehicle vehicle ,Rtype.MOD.version[0].versionModified.ts ts,Rtype.MOD.version[0].versionModified.founder founder,Rtype.MOD.version[0].versionModified.state state from json_serde_table;
Query ID = root_20170412170606_a674d31b-31d7-477b-b9ff-3ebd76636cf8
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1491484583384_0018, Tracking URL = http://mac127:8088/proxy/application_1491484583384_0018/
Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1491484583384_0018
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2017-04-12 17:06:44,990 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-04-12 17:06:53,361 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.8 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 1 seconds 800 msec
Ended Job = job_1491484583384_0018
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 1.8 sec   HDFS Read: 4891 HDFS Write: 50 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 seconds 800 msec
OK
1       ns      Mh-3412 2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z        3.0     Florida
Time taken: 19.745 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: colon (:) is missing in your json data after "versionModified" field

Comment: Why would you download a JSON SerDe when it is already a part of the distribution?

Comment: you are right same can be done with org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde , i have just tried and it gives me same result.. i will edit my answer.. thanks

Comment: Thanks you all for great help..my source is a table and this entire json content in one column . in that case how do i load?

Comment: i also done it in a single column only, just check the create table script, here we have a single column RType

Comment: waht i was telling lis like...instead of using load data local inpath '/root/json.txt' INTO TABLE json_serde_table  this json.txt itself is in another table as a column

Comment: added new question for insert... can you help @Dudu