# inserting JSON data from one table to another tables in HIVE

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I want to insert JSON data from one table to other tables based on the key fields on the data.

my data looks like this

> {"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC":{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}
>
> {"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"GAP":{"XVY":"123.dfer","FAH":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}
>
> {"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"BOX":{"VOG":"123.dfer","FAH":"3.0","FAX":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}

Here based on Version, whther it is "BOX" or "GAP" or "ABC" i want to populate the fields on particular JSON rows to another table

for ex: if version is "GAP" then populate particular rows in one table if it is "BOX" then populate to another tables...  I mean all rows for BOX...

how can I achieve this using HIVE. Please help.

NOTE: My JSON data is in one table as a column with type string

Comment: Is there always only a single element within the array?

Comment: The JSON was invalid (missing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Demo**

```
create table src (myjson string);

insert into src values
    ('{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC":{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}')
   ,('{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"GAP":{"XVY":"123.dfer","FAH":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}')
   ,('{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"BOX":{"VOG":"123.dfer","FAH":"3.0","FAX":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}')
;

create table trg_abc (myjson string);
create table trg_gap (myjson string);
create table trg_box (myjson string);
```

---

```
from src
insert into trg_abc select myjson where get_json_object(myjson,'$.Rtype.MOD.Version[0].ABC') is not null
insert into trg_gap select myjson where get_json_object(myjson,'$.Rtype.MOD.Version[0].GAP') is not null
insert into trg_box select myjson where get_json_object(myjson,'$.Rtype.MOD.Version[0].BOX') is not null
;
```

Comment: Thanks @Dudu..          one more doubt what if i have many elements like inside "ABC"   for ex:    ('{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC":{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"},{"XYZ":"555.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"CHINA","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"},{"XYZ":"888.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"JAPAN","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}')      in tat case will it work ?

Comment: How can it possibly matter?

Comment: array <struct<>>

Comment: what is the difference from the previous version?

Comment: i wanted to get data like this from trg_ab     ver    XYZ   1 123.dfer   1 555.defr  etc... lateral view required i guess

Comment: created aother qn please help @Dudu Markovitz  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449688/json-parsing-issue-in-hive

Answer (score -1):

First of all you will need to store your data as json in hive tables:

I assume your hive table is EXTERNAL (usually are - check it with `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`).
If so the entire dataset lies in some hdfs/s3 path, for example `s3a://your_bucket/your_jsons_location/`

Download json-udf-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar and run  `ADD JARS s3a://your_bucket/lib/json-udf-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar;`
Then you must create a dedicated json table for each json schema you have:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE boxes
(Rtype struct<ver:string,os:string,type:string,vehicle:string,MOD:struct<Version:array<struct<BOX:struct<VOG:string,FAH:string,FAX:string,fashion:string,cdc:string,dof:string,ts:string>>>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' location 's3a://your_bucket/your_jsons_location/';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE gaps
(Rtype struct<ver:string,os:string,type:string,vehicle:string,MOD:struct<Version:array<struct<GAP:struct<XVY:string,FAH:string,GHT:string,fashion:string,cdc:string,dof:string,ts:string>>>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' location 's3a://your_bucket/your_jsons_location/';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abcs
(Rtype struct<ver:string,os:string,type:string,vehicle:string,MOD:struct<Version:array<struct<ABC:struct<XYZ:string,founder:string,GHT:string,fashion:string,cdc:string,dof:string,ts:string>>>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' location 's3a://your_jsons_location/';
```

Now if you'll run:

```
SELECT * FROM boxes;
SELECT * FROM gaps;
SELECT * FROM abcs;
```

you will see that each table parsed correctly only the matching jsons (according to the schema that was specified in the create statment).
The unmatching ones in each table are NULL.

To filter out the unrelevant records run:
`SELECT * FROM abcs WHERE Rtype.mod.version[0].abc IS NOT NULL;`

**Note**: that this whole explanation assumes that your jsons are stored externally to the hive table (specifically I used S3 but it can also be HDFS)

Comment: my JSON data already in a HIVe table as a column with data type String....   i want to segregate this into another hive table with some filtered fileds...i am not getting how to get array elemtes like "FASHION" from the column

Comment: i cannot get the location of my source table that contain json data as string....   can u tell me how to get the valus for "fashion".. i tried this Rtype.mod.version[0].fashion  but getting NULL

Comment: This is your suggested solution? Causing deliberately parsing errors?

Comment: Well I was indeed unaware of the 'get_json_object' string function which offers an easier solution. However, in my answer, the deliberate parsing error as you put it, is just a one-time obsticle after which you can create tables for each json schema type and query them with a much better performance. (SerDe obviously being faster then the parsing function). I would add to my solution 2 small steps: `CREATE TABLE abcs_final LIKE abcs` + `INSERT INTO abcs_final SELECT * FROMabcs WHERE Rtype.mod.version[0].abc IS NOT NULL;`. Either way this answer does solve the problem - unjust downvote

Comment: You have created 3 tables instead of one which means you are going to scan the data 3 times and you also ignored the INSERT aspect which is the essence of this post