# JSON parsing issue in hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

i am getting some issues while querying json data.

my sample data look like ...

> {"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC":{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}
>
> {"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"GAP":{"GGG":"123.dfer","FFF":"3.0","DDD":"Florida","GOP":"fg45","cdc":"QQQ","ZZZ":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}
>
> {"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"BOX":{"FRG":"123.dfer","CXD":"3.0","FAX":"Florida","SXD":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}

i have done follwing

> create table src (myjson string);
>
> insert into src values
>       ('{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC":{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}')
>   ,('{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"GAP":{"XVY":"123.dfer","FAH":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}')
>   ,('{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"BOX":{"VOG":"123.dfer","FAH":"3.0","FAX":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}')
>   ;

The issue is when i start do `select get_json_object(myjson,'$.Rtype.MOD.Version[0].ABC.fashion') where get_json_object(myjson,'$.Rtype.MOD.Version[0].ABC') is not null  from src`

am getting NULLS for the some fields

count value for this say 2345
without where condition also countvalue 2345. this is the issue

the observasion i have seen is this is due to it is trying to fetch data that is `$.Rtype.MOD.Version[0].GAP`

Answer (score 0):

```
hive> load data local inpath '/home/satish/s.json' into table sjson;

Loading data to table hivelearning.sjson
Table hivelearning.sjson stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=216]

hive> select * from sjson;

{"Rtype":{"ver":"1","os":"ms","type":"ns","vehicle":"Mh-3412","MOD":{"Version":[{"ABC":{"XYZ":"123.dfer","founder":"3.0","GHT":"Florida","fashion":"fg45","cdc":"new","dof":"yes","ts":"2000-04-01T00:00:00.171Z"}}]}}}

Time taken: 1.297 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select get_json_object(data,'$.Rtype.MOD.Version[0].ABC.fashion') from sjson;

OK

fg45

Time taken: 0.084 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answers

Comment: above question Query was wrong they had given where clause in a wrong place so if he give  where clause (after from src) like
then he will get exact output

 `select get_json_object(myjson,'$.Rtype.MOD.Version[0].ABC.fashion') FROM src where get_json_object(myjson,'$.Rtype.MOD.Version[0].ABC') is not null`