# Cassandra stored JSON array parsing in tableau

Tags: cassandra, jsonpath, spark-cassandra-connector, tableau-api

I am working with tableau and need to parse JSON array which has stored in Apache Cassandra.
I could able make connect tableau with Cassandra through spark as described [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tableau-spark-cassandra).
I have succeeded to parse JSON object by using jsonpath, but I don't get a solution to parse JSON array.

Please see the sample structure of my data

> [{    "name": "Obama" },{     "name": "Barak" }]

Any suggestion please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447428/parse-json-arrays-using-hive) link to get solution for this.

I have applied bellow solution from the reference

```
SELECT 
    get_json_object(concat(concat('{"root":', jt.value), '}'), '$.root')
FROM jt;
```