# Read json string data

Tags: hive

I have the below column product_details where I want to extract the code where the colour is green.

Column - product_details

```
"[
{\"colour\":\"red\",\"code\":1,\"id\":111\"},{\"colour\":\"blue\",\"code\":4,\"id\":222\"},{\"colour\":\"green\",\"code\":6,\"id\":333\"}
]"
```

o/p: 6

I tried `regex_replace` and `regex_extract` to get the value. But not successful.

Comment: Trying to parse json (or xml, html etc) with regex is usually a bad idea, since regex doesn't work well with structures like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse json arrays using HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447428/parse-json-arrays-using-hive)